# Stable recovery of signals by $\ell_1$ optimization

Tags: reference-request, approximation-algorithms, sparse-matrix, compressed-sensing, stable

Suppose the received vector $y$ is generated from a vector $x^*$ as $y = { D}x^* + z$ for some ``dictionary" matrix ${D}$ and noise vector $z$ s.t for some $\epsilon >0$ we have, $\Vert z \Vert_2 \leq \epsilon$.

Now we solve the so-called $P_1^\epsilon$ optimization question to get, $\hat{x} := \min \Vert x \Vert_1 \text{ s.t } \Vert {D}x - y \Vert _2 \leq \epsilon$.

- Then *under certan RIP conditions on D*  and some constant $C$ it follows that, $\Vert x^* - \hat{x} \Vert \leq C \epsilon$. Can someone kindly reference me the exact theorem and proof of this statement?

---

Are there more general forms of such a result? 
I would be glad to get some references in that direction too.

Comment: See Chapter 10 of Vershynin's book: https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html